# Django Rest Framework - Custom error messages - Serializer vs. Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, validationerror

:) Hello!

I'm currently facing a problem that I am not being able to solve by searching the documentation or other questions, if someone can help I would be very grateful.

The problem is relatively of simple: I am adding custom messages for validation errors that come up when posting a new object, but I'd like to do it in one place only: inside model OR inside serializer.

For the sake of this example and my use case, I am talking only about `unique` and `max_length` validations.

- Defining `error_messages=errors_dict` inside the model fields currently only changes the `unique` validation error message, displaying the default for `max_length`.
- The opposite happens when I set it inside the serializer, using extra_kwargs inside Meta. It only changes the `max_length` validation error message.

Does anyone know what I am missing here? Is it possible to set the `error_messages` in only one place?

Thank you!

---

Here are some code snippets, if it helps:

`errors` in the below examples is the same dictionary, containing both keys (`unique` and `max_length`).

- Inside Model, working only for the unique validation:

```
class User(AbstractUser, SplintModel):
    (...)
    cpf = models.CharField('CPF', blank=False, max_length=11, unique=True, error_messages=errors)
```

- Inside Serializer, working only for the max_length validation:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    (...)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        (...)

        extra_kwargs = {
            "cpf": {"error_messages": errors}
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your **serializers.py**:

```
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator

    extra_kwargs = {
       'cpf': { 
                {
                  'error_messages' : {"max_length": "your error"},
                  'validators': [
                      UniqueValidator(
                         queryset=User.objects.all(),
                         message="write your error message here"
                )
             ]
        }
     }
```

Comment: I will accept your answer because it complies with what I requested. 
However, I still get the impression that this is not the ideal way to make this change, as the custom error message for the UniqueValidator is outside the errors dictionary. 

I'll give it a few more tries based on your suggestion.

Thanks!